# Clicking OK in a dialog box

Tags: user-interface, button, automation, windows-10, autoit

I'm running a program after Windows 10 starts up and it gives me the dialog box attached. All I need to do is automate clicking the OK button. The script I've written isn't working :

```
WinActivate("RoomView Express Login")

If WinActivate("RoomView Express Login") Then
   ControlClick("RoomView Express Login", "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:3]")
EndIf
```

How to correctly do this? I've attached AutoIt Window Info of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
While Not WinExists("RoomView Express Login")
   Sleep(50)
WEnd

If WinActivate("RoomView Express Login") Then
   ControlClick("RoomView Express Login", "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:3]")
EndIf
```

this would be my solution

Answer (score -1):

> The script I've written isn't working so far …

Executes before targeted window's appearance possibly. As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `WinWait()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) :

> Pauses execution of the script until the requested window exists.

Also returns a handle. Example:

```
Global Const $g_iTimeout  = 0
Global Const $g_sWndTitle = 'RoomView Express Login'
Global Const $g_sWndText  = ''
Global Const $g_sControl  = '[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:3]'

Global       $g_hWnd      = WinWait($g_sWndTitle, $g_sWndText, $g_iTimeout)
Global       $g_hCtrl     = ControlGetHandle($g_hWnd, $g_sWndText, $g_sControl); Or ControlGetHandle($g_sWndTitle, $g_sWndText, $g_sControl)

ControlClick($g_hWnd, $g_sWndText, $g_hCtrl); Or ControlClick($g_sWndTitle, $g_sWndText, $g_sControl)
```

[Documentation - Function Reference - `ControlClick()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm).